# wpf textbox background color not work

Tags: wpf, background, textbox, styles

```
   <Style x:Key="TextInputStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="#FF7F98DC" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="#FF7E97F0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This is a part of my App.xaml code.

It is style for textBox.

But Background Property didn't work.

Others work well.

Please help me. Why can't I change background color of TextBox?

Comment: Control template is causing the problem, remove ControlTemplate and try it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving a background to your text box, instead you should give the background to your border because it has been defined in the control template.

```
    <Style x:Key="TextInputStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="#FF7F98DC" BorderThickness="1" ***Background="Red"***>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="#FF7E97F0"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Please see the Border tag inside ControlTemplate above.